# Global static variable suddenly becoming 0 in local function - why?

Tags: c

I've got some general header where I declare it (in `std.h`):

```
static volatile unsigned int timestamp;
```

I've got Interruption where I increase it (in `main.c`):

```
void ISR_Pit(void) {
    unsigned int status;
    /// Read the PIT status register
    status = PIT_GetStatus() & AT91C_PITC_PITS;
    if (status != 0) {
        /// 1 = The Periodic Interval timer has reached PIV since the last read of PIT_PIVR.
        /// Read the PIVR to acknowledge interrupt and get number of ticks
        ///Returns the number of occurrences of periodic intervals since the last read of PIT_PIVR.
        timestamp += (PIT_GetPIVR() >> 20);
        //printf(" --> TIMERING :: %u \n\r", timestamp);
        }
    }
```

in another module I've got procedure where I must use it (in `meta.c`):

```
void Wait(unsigned long delay) {
    volatile unsigned int start = timestamp;
    unsigned int elapsed;
    do {
        elapsed = timestamp;
        elapsed -= start;
        //printf(" --> TIMERING :: %u \n\r", timestamp);
        }
    while (elapsed < delay);
    }
```

first `printf` shows correct increasing `timestamp` but Wait `printf` always shows `0`. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declare your variable as `static`, which means its local to the file it is included in. The `timestamp` in `main.c` is different than the one in `meta.c`.

You can fix that by declaring `timestamp` in `main.c` like so:

```
volatile unsigned int timestamp = 0;
```

and in `meta.c` like so:

```
extern volatile unsigned int timestamp;
```

Comment: thank you. truly stupid mistake, were thinking about static in C# :)